# How to set a default order using the primary key for all the rows in a psql database?

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

Is there a way to set a default order for all the rows in a table so that I can always retrieve the queryset in the same order in postgres?

Comment: No. But you could use a VIEW that has an ORDER BY

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default order" in a relational database. The only way to get a guaranteed sort order in a result is to use `ORDER BY`